# Integrate $f'(x)$ with respect to $f(x)$

Tags: integration

It'd make sense to integrate it with respect to $x$. But can you integrate it with respect to $f(x)$?

Comment: More generally, we have $\int g df = \int gf' dx$. For example, $\int f' df = \int f'^2 dx$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in some sense, if you view $f(x)$ as giving a measure on the real line.  Google "Stieltjes integral" for more.  The relation between $f$ and $f'$ is unimportant here, though.